# compilation error on Executing embedded lua in C file

Tags: c, gcc, linker, lua, cygwin

I am using Cygwin environment with Lua Interpreter package included while cygwin installation.
So I am able to compile and run sample lua progs.
But when i try to execute a sample c file which has lua calls , i am always getting this following error.

```
$ cc -o ../samples/ctest -Wall  ../samples/ctest.c
/tmp/ccOYgLj4.o:ctest.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `_luaL_newstate'
/tmp/ccOYgLj4.o:ctest.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `_luaL_openlibs'
/tmp/ccOYgLj4.o:ctest.c:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `_luaL_loadfile'
/tmp/ccOYgLj4.o:ctest.c:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `_lua_pcall'
/tmp/ccOYgLj4.o:ctest.c:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `_lua_getfield'
/tmp/ccOYgLj4.o:ctest.c:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `_lua_call'
/tmp/ccOYgLj4.o:ctest.c:(.text+0xf0): undefined reference to `_lua_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My sample ctest.c file contents:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

/* lua interpreter */
lua_State* l;

int main () {
  int dofile;

  /* initialize lua */
  l = lua_open();

  /* load lua libraries */
  luaL_openlibs(l);

  /* run the hello.lua script */
  dofile = luaL_dofile(l, "hello.lua");

  if (dofile == 0) {
    /* call foo */
    lua_getglobal(l,"foo");
    lua_call(l,0,0);
  }
  else {
    printf("Error, unable to run hello.lua\n");
  }

  /* cleanup Lua */
  lua_close(l);

  return 0;
}

hello.lua file contents:
print("from c hurray")
```

on searching the net everywhere they say some linker error and have to include -llua51. So i tried the following .

```
$ cc -o ../samples/ctest -Wall -llua5.1 ../samples/ctest.c
/tmp/cc3v5Nim.o:ctest.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `_luaL_newstate'
/tmp/cc3v5Nim.o:ctest.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `_luaL_openlibs'
/tmp/cc3v5Nim.o:ctest.c:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `_luaL_loadfile'
/tmp/cc3v5Nim.o:ctest.c:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `_lua_pcall'
/tmp/cc3v5Nim.o:ctest.c:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `_lua_getfield'
/tmp/cc3v5Nim.o:ctest.c:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `_lua_call'
/tmp/cc3v5Nim.o:ctest.c:(.text+0xf0): undefined reference to `_lua_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Vedhashree@Vedhashree-PC /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin
$ ls /usr/lib/liblua*.a
/usr/lib/liblua.a      /usr/lib/liblua5.1.a
/usr/lib/liblua.dll.a  /usr/lib/liblua5.1.dll.a
```

Can you help me fix this issue and make my first embedded lua c program work?

#### Update:

```
$ cc -o ctesing -Wall ctesting.c -llua5.1
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find
 -llua5.1
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

-----------------------------------------------------------------
cc -o ../samples/ctest -Wall ../samples/ctest.c -llua 
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find
 -llua51
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
-----------------------------------------------------------------

cc -o ../samples/ctest -Wall ../samples/ctest.c -llua51 
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find
 -llua
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Still I get only these errors :(

Answer (score 5):

Place `-llua5.1` after `../samples/ctest.c`. Objects should be linked in reverse order of dependency.

```
cc -o ../samples/ctest -Wall ../samples/ctest.c -llua5.1
```

**UPDATE:** Your update describes a different problem. In this case the linker cannot find a liblua5.1.a file in its search path. Make sure that you have such a library on your system and try adding its path using the [-L option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

Comment: $ cc -o ctest ctest.c /usr/lib/liblua.a